# dashing dashboard - calheatmap widget (resque_heatmap.coffee) removes cells after Load Next/Previous Domains

Tags: coffeescript, heatmap, dashboard, dashing

I'm using calheatmap widget in dashing dashboard.

After clicking next (or previous) button, new domain in widget contains no-data until next json data receiving.

How can i import data to widget for all 2 days, constantly...

### Some lines of resque_heatmap.coffee as follows

```
    @startDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), (now.getHours()-4)).getTime()
    @firstDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), (now.getDate()-1))
    @lastDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), (now.getDate()+1))
    @calheatmap.init({
      start: @startDate, 
      itemSelector: "#resque-scheduled-heatmap",      
      range: 5,
      afterLoad: ->
        @calheatmap.update(data.items)
      afterLoadNextDomain: (date) ->
        @calheatmap.update(data.items)
      afterLoadPreviousDomain: (date) ->
        @calheatmap.update(data.items)
      previousSelector: "#previous",
      nextSelector: "#next",
      cellSize: 7,
      minDate: @firstDate,
      maxDate: @lastDate,
      domainGutter: 5,      
      legend: d3.range(legendStep, @maxJobPerMinute + legendStep, legendStep),
      legendCellSize: 7,
      displayLegend: true,
      itemName: "enerji uretim",
      subDomainDateFormat: "%H:%M",
      subDomainTitleFormat: {
        empty: "{date} 0",
        filled: "{date} {count}"
      }
      label: {
        height: 50
      }
    })
```

Thank you

Comment: the `afterLoadNextDomain` and other callback functions are not necessary. You are just restating the default values. It is normal that you have to wait for the json, as it's giving the data your calendar need. You can not get more data than what the calendar need at any time.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved with;

1. changing afterLoad line to this:
   afterLoad: ->
   $.getJSON 'http://10.10.114.11:3000/data/heatmap.json
2. removing afterLoadNextDomain and afterLoadPreviousDomain as you said
3. adding a new line to onData: section as follows:

onData: (data) ->
    if @calheatmap
        @calheatmap.options.data = data.items